# Reading Json object using map()

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I have a json object like below
`{"Title":"asb","Date":"2019","Other":"not important"}`
What is the correct way to read this object and render in `<ul><li>`?

**Note**
I tried this by assigning this to a state and iterate state using `map()`, but it is not working.

Comment: It is depend on how you want to show your data

Comment: What do you mean, not working? Are you receiving an error? If so, what is error message?

Comment: Could you please be more specific ?

Comment: If this is not array of object then `map` wont work

Comment: Hi @brk then what is the best way to do this? one method I tried was, define a new array variable in render method , push the state to that new array and then reading the array object using map() method.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do

Comment: @brk requirement is to read this json object {"Title":"asb","Date":"2019","Other":"not important"} and display in <li></li>

Comment: Look at @bird's answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: There's no such thing as a _JSON Object_. JSON is _always_ a string.

Comment: Hi @user633183 then what does this mean ?
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: @Kevin w3schools is notorious for providing inaccurate information and bad advice

Comment: @Kevin to clarify, that is a plain object.

Answer (score 2):

`map` can use with Array only, not Object. Use `Object.entries` to convert the object to an array first

```js
const data = {"Title":"asb","Date":"2019","Other":"not important"}

const App = () => 
   <ul> 
     {
       Object.entries(data).map(([key, val]) => <li>{key}: {val}</li>)
     }
    </ul>
  
  
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an object, so `map` won't work. Iterate over `Object.entries` instead:

```js
const object = {"Title":"asb","Date":"2019","Other":"not important"};
Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value]) => document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += `<li>${key}: ${value}</li>`);
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

For object , you can use for loop , map is better use for array type

```js
var data = {"Title":"asb","Date":"2019","Other":"not important"};

for(var i in data) {
  var htm = `<li>${i} : ${data[i]}</li>`;
  test.innerHTML += htm; 
}
```

```html
<ul id=test></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly read see bellow example:
**case 1 :**

```
var text  = { "Title": "asb", "Date": "2019", "Other": "not important" };
console.log(text.Date)
```

**output :2019**

**case 2:**

after convert and used

```
var s = '{"first_name" : "Sammy", "last_name" : "Shark", "location" : "Ocean"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(s);
```